# How to fix this git issue Error response from daemon: Bad response from Docker engine

Tags: docker

This is so strange I get docker daemon error when try to commit (git).
[image]
I am using git bash on windows 10.

How to fix this?

Comment: This is not a Git issue, it's purely a Docker thing. You'd get the same result from a non-Git command trying to do the same thing to the same files.

Comment: @torek , ok. But why a simple git command needs to care about docker issue? I don't understand

Comment: What's the error?  What command are you running?  What tool produced the image you included in the question?

Comment: The Git command is trying to read or write a file. The Docker system is refusing to respond correctly. The operating system times out, or gets a bad response, and delivers the "bad response from Docker engine" error message. *Git* has no idea that this is a Docker problem! The OS just tells Git "your operation on the file failed".

Comment: @DavidMaze, this is soucetree. the error is about docker daemon: "Error response from daemon: Bad response from Docker engine" when containers are down

Comment: Containers are implemented by Docker (not your OS, not Git). You must fix the down-ness of your Docker system.

Comment: @torek ok, how can I fix this docker issue?

Comment: I have no idea. You're using Windows. I've only used Docker on Linux.